# Java constructor vs static method

Tags: java, constructor

I just started programming in Java and encountered a strange problem concerning printing an object.

When a new object of type gast is created, the user has to enter his or her birthday. This all works fine, however, it shows "0-0-0" when I print it. Why is that?

By the way, if I create a new Datum object directly with the parameter constructor it works fine. Wherein lies the problem? I just can't figure it out.

```
public class Datum {
    private static String patroon = "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}";
    public int dag;
    public int maand;
    public int jaar;

    Datum() {
        newDatum();
    }

    Datum(int dag, int maand, int jaar) {
        System.out.print("constructor: " + dag);
        this.dag = dag;
        System.out.println(", dag: " + this.dag);
        this.maand = maand;
        this.jaar = jaar;
    }

    /* Static Method */
    public static Datum newDatum() {
        String input = Opgave5.userInput("Geboortedatum gast"); 
        boolean b = input.matches(patroon); 

        if (b) {
            String[] str = input.split("-");

            int dag = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
            int maand = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
            int jaar = Integer.parseInt(str[2]);

            Datum datum = new Datum(dag, maand, jaar);
            System.out.println(datum);
            return datum;
        }
        else {
            return new Datum();
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.dag + "-" + this.maand + "-" + this.jaar;
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
Gast() {
    this.firstName = Opgave5.userInput("Voornaam gast");
    this.lastName = Opgave5.userInput("Achternaam gast");
    this.geboortedatum = new Datum();

    System.out.println("gast: " + this.geboortedatum); // <--- this prints out 0-0-0

}

public String toString() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.geboortedatum;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't understand constructors in Java. You are merely ignoring the result of `newDatum()` in the constructor. Also, if it did have the expected effect, it might recurse infinitely in the constructor invocation inside `newDatum()`. Use something like this; allowing `newDatum()` to edit the instance will work:

```
Datum() {
    newDatum(this);
}

public static void newDatum(Datum instance) {
    String input = Opgave5.userInput("Geboortedatum gast"); 
    boolean b = input.matches(patroon); 

    if (b) {
        String[] str = input.split("-");

        int dag = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
        int maand = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
        int jaar = Integer.parseInt(str[2]);

        instance.dag = dag;
        instance.maand = maand;
        instance.jaar = jaar;
        System.out.println(instance);
    }
    else {
        new Datum();
    }
    // ^^ Above code may be buggy, see my answer above code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
this.geboortedatum = new Datum();
```

Is using the default constructor.  This will set no values.  Try to pass the parameters in via constructor like this:

```
this.geboortedatum = new Datum(1, 2, 3);
```

If you want to take advantage of the `static` method you wrote (which is where you ask for user input), then do the following:

```
this.geboortedatum = Datum.newDatum();
```

Comment: I know it works if I use the constructor that way. The point is I need to process the data via userInput.

Comment: Unfortunately adding changing newDatum() to Datum.newDatum() does not work. They both refer to the same method, so this makes sense :)